# IE 11 broke all our sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, internet-explorer-11

When Microsoft rolled out IE 11 on the automatic updates it broke all our sites.

For example, one of our sites started getting a weird string in the URL. After the '/' the following gets added.

(F(IZOtnSYyVIaxfgEbqezGvIKHeTq8scRxJzvlSVK2airuqpB29zOonBkpv3_Lf61u7hveLZH053qcPgI6cTpejnOWojBJBiePNrC1Z7lShzsKs7VdayYOlA9dF_vIodMiRbUCzDRHbf9UlxsYNbuo_UabOT81))

And because of this nothing on the site works.

Adding the site to Compatibility View in IE 11 works. But what has Microsoft done with IE 11 that destroys everything?

Is there anyway to fix this without having to add the site to Compatibility view?

Comment: Nothing generates the code, it came when IE 11 was released.

Answer (score 3):

What you see is a forms authentication ticket, sent in the url, instead of a cookie. ASP.NET thinks that you are using an unknown browser that cannot handle cookies, JavaScript, etc. You should update your browser definition files. A similar issue has actually happened with IE10, not 11: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Or, as a workaround for this one case only, modify your [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and force forms to use cookies. But it won't solve all your problems.

Comment: What I can see, it is already set to use cookies.

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="480" />
    </authentication>

Comment: You seem to be mistaken. You don't specify the cookieless attribute. The default setting is UseDeviceProfile. Which exactly means that the browser detection mechanism will be used. Which in this case says that cookies cannot be used. But like I said, don't focus on this, it's only a partial solution anyway. Although you can use it to test the browser detection mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Try install last windows updates. It helped us this the same situation.

Comment: There are now available updates from our vsus server, so the latest are applied.